# Sql search, one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Is there a way to get all components and its properties for a specific computer with a sql search?

Comment: From that schema seems that the only existing components are cpus... is that right, or are there more entities?

Comment: There are many more to come

Comment: There probably is. What have you tried so far? What's the expected output?

Comment: http://imgur.com/6qobJFo

Comment: This is so not what @Shadow was asking for... [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

```
select manufacturer,price,imglink,cores,brand,clock_frequency 
from computer
inner join computer_has_comp on computer.computer_id=computer_has_comp.computer_computer_id 
inner join cpu on computer_has_comp.compid=cpu.compid
```

Comment: This query inner joins all those three tables.Table computer and table computer_has_comp has a common column "computer_id",so first we joined those tables.Then table computer_has_comp and table cpu has common column "compid",so we joined it.By doing this three tables are joined and we can select the required columns from the three tables.

Comment: I think you should explain a little to the OP in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If I identified the relations right, this might work..

```
SELECT computer.*, computer_has_comp.*, cpu.* FROM computer 
LEFT JOIN computer_has_comp ON computer.computer_id=computer_has_comp.computer_computer_id
LEFT JOIN cpu ON computer_has_comp.compid=cpu.compid
```

Comment: what kind of data will this generate?

Comment: all components and its properties for a specific computer

Comment: @Fluff - What a strange question. A sql query will generate a resultset what you do with it is up to you.